# Writing a GET endpoint for the Spotify API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, spotify

I am using the johnnycrazy C#/.NET wrapper for my Spotify API project: https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/

What I am attempting to do is write an endpoint to get a single Album.

I've decided to go the route of ClientCredentialsAuth, where I make a POST request to handle getting the token: https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET/blob/master/SpotifyAPI.Docs/docs/SpotifyWebAPI/auth.md#clientcredentialsauth

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuth()
{
    CredentialsAuth auth = new CredentialsAuth("_clientId", "_clientPass");
    Token token = await auth.GetToken();
    SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI() { TokenType = token.TokenType, AccessToken = token.AccessToken };

    return Ok(api);
}
```

Now I need to write an endpoint that utilizes this, and that will get a single album.

This is the supposed usage for getting an album:

```cs
FullAlbum album = _spotify.GetAlbum("5O7V8l4SeXTymVp3IesT9C");
Console.WriteLine(album.Name + "| Popularity: " + album.Popularity); //Display name and Popularity
```

But It's just unclear to me as to how I'm supposed to write a complete GET endpoint, using these custom classes. So far, I have this:

```cs
private static SpotifyWebAPI _spotify;

// GET single Album
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSingleAlbum(int id)
{
    FullAlbum album = _spotify.GetAlbum("2KhkdN53S255mwgjrHUhho");

    if (album == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"No album found with id of {id}");
    }

    return Ok(album);
}
```

Any help to point me in the right direction, and get me on track, would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You've posted a link to documentation with good working code, but you seem to have totally disregarded it. You need to literally do something like:

```
CredentialsAuth auth = new CredentialsAuth(_clientId, _secretId);
Token token = await auth.GetToken();
SpotifyWebAPI api = new SpotifyWebAPI() {TokenType = token.TokenType, AccessToken = token.AccessToken};

FullAlbum = api.GetAlbum("2KhkdN53S255mwgjrHUhho");

if (album == null)
{
    return NotFound($"No album found with id of {id}");
}

return Ok(album);
```

In other words, you need to actually authorize the Spotify API class, and then make your actual request.

Comment: Ahhh ok, that makes sense. My problem I think was I just stared at my code for too long, and was overthinking things (as per usual). Thank you for your help!

Comment: It happens. FWIW, you probably shouldn't actually be doing this for *every* request, though. Ideally, this would be factored away into a wrapper class, and then you'd conditionally authorize only when there's no token yet, or that token has expired and you need to refresh. However, the logic for how to build that is very dependent on the library you're using. (There might even be a built-in methodology). I don't know enough about this library to help you out there.

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense. There's no need to rinse and repeat those few lines of code each time. Thanks again, I greatly appreciate it!